# Does BlackRock own 15% of Fox News?

Tags: media, pharmaceutical, corporate-finance

In a recent [YouTube live stream by The Grayzone](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=q0BV_lf5eHU&ab_channel=TheGrayzone), the hosts, Max Blumenthal and Aaron Mate, stated (~8m:53s) that investment management firms, [Vanguard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Vanguard_Group) and [BlackRock](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BlackRock) are:

> the two largest owners of Pfizer. They’re the two biggest owners of Johnson and Johnson
> [...]
> They own over 4-like 15% of Fox. Sorry, they own 13% of Johnson and Johnson, and like 15% of Moderna.

Is this true?

Answer (score 12):

### They own 15.1% of Fox's shares

[Fintel](https://fintel.io/so/us/foxa/blackrock) summarizes the [SEC filing](https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1364742/000130655023005977/us35137l1052_020123.txt):

> 2023-02-01 - BlackRock Inc. has filed an SC 13G/A form with the Securities and Exchange Commission (SEC) disclosing ownership of 45,743,746 shares of Fox Corporation - Class A (US:FOXA). This represents 15.1 percent ownership of the company. In their previous filing dated 2022-01-27 , BlackRock Inc. had reported owning 39,865,263 shares, indicating an increase of 14.75 percent.

Fintel tracks historical data. At the start of the pandemic, BlackRock owned 10% of Fox shares. As an investment company, they own a [lot of shares in a lot of other companies](https://fintel.io/i/blackrock).

For context, [Investor.gov](https://www.investor.gov/introduction-investing/investing-basics/glossary/schedules-13d-and-13g) explains what 13D and 13G filings are.

Shareholders elect Fox's [board of directors](https://www.foxcorporation.com/corporate-governance/statement-corporate-governance/). According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fox_Corporation#:%7E:text=The%20company%20is%20controlled%20by,trust%20with%2039.6%25%20ownership%20share.&text=U.S.):

> The company is controlled by the Murdoch family via a family trust with 39.6% ownership share. Rupert Murdoch is chair, while his son Lachlan Murdoch is executive chair and CEO.

Comment: Vanguard is huge. It manages $13 TRILLION on behalf of their investors. That does not meant they "own" it though - in vanguard's case, a lot of that is retirement funds, 401k plan, etc, that's invested in mutual funds.

Answer (score 4):

True, as already addressed by [PolitiFact](https://www.politifact.com/factchecks/2023/apr/26/facebook-posts/blackrock-fox-and-tucker-carlson-untangling-a-web/) on 26 April 2023:

> BlackRock owned 45.7 million shares of Fox Corp. as of Feb. 1, according to a [Fintel filing](https://fintel.io/so/us/foxa/blackrock). That’s 15.1% ownership of the company.

Comment: Okay but what is the nature of the ownership and does it suggest control?

Comment: @Seekinganswers: If you have a separate question, you should post that separately